# Explanation of network indices normalization

Tags: math, networkx, graph-theory, network-analysis

Could someone explain in pretty simple words why the normalization of many network analysis indicies (graph theory) is n(n - 1), where n – the graph size? Why do we need to take into account (n - 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most network measures that focus on counting edges (e.g. clustering coefficient) are normalized by the total number of possible edges.  Since every edge connects a pair of vertices, we need to know how many possible pairs of vertices we can make.  There are n possible vertices we could choose as the source of our edge, and therefore there are n-1 possible vertices that could be the target of our edge (assuming no self-loops, and if undirected divide by 2 bc source and target are exchangeable).  Hence, you frequently encounter $n(n-1)$ or $\binomal{n}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Did I understand correctly that this is only true for simple graphs? If graph is multigraph, the number of possible edges could be any? Hence, there is no unambiguous formula?